# Deployer is not uploading new files in Symfony 6 application

Tags: symfony, symfony6, php-deployer

I am deploying an application to a remote server using Deployer. I have updated the code in the local environment and when I deploy it the new files do not appear on the remote server.

For example, I've created a `HomeController.php` file, but it doesn't show up on the remote server.

The deployment tasks do not give any errors, having executed the command:

```
dep deploy -vvv
```

The end result is the following after several messages:

```
[im] info successfully deployed!
```

A new folder with the new release is created on the remote server, but the new files are not present.

This is my file **`deploy.yaml`**:

```
import:
  - recipe/symfony.php

config:
  repository: 'git@github.com:myuser/myrepository.git'
  git_ssh_command: 'ssh'
  http_user: remoteuser
  composer_options: '--verbose --no-progress --no-interaction --ignore-platform-req=php'

hosts:
  im:
    remote_user: remoteuser
    deploy_path: '~/rootfolder'
    stage: production

tasks:
  build:
    - run: uptime

after:
  deploy:failed: deploy:unlock
```

Do I have to do something extra for the new files to be included?